# I want to nest a model into the Serialiazer. Category' object has no attribute 'brand_set'

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I want to nest a model into the serializer. Like on list of Category, there should be fields from Brand model, But I m getting error by on setting this way ?

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    #....


class Brand(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="category")
    #....
```

Serializers

```
class CategorySerializerNested(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    brands = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_brands(self, obj):
        brands = obj.brand_set.all() #this thin popping error how to fix that....
        serializer = BrandSerializerNested(brands, many=True)
        return serializer.data


class BrandSerializerNested(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_products(self, obj):
        products = obj.product_set.all()
        serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
        return serializer.data

    class Meta:
        model = Brand
        fields = '__all__'
```

View.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def getCategoryWithBrands(request, pk):
    category = Category.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializer = CategorySerializerNested(category, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

url.py

```
path('nested/<str:pk>/', views.getCategoryWithBrands,
         name="category-with-brands"),
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'Category' object has no attribute 'brand_set'
[02/Feb/2022 03:24:49] "GET /api/v1/categories/nested/1/ HTTP/1.1" 500 125121
```

I'm sure im doing something illogical but i dont know now, please help me to fix this , if there's any better way to do that please also help there as well. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you specified `related_name='category'`, you obtain the related `Brand`s with:

```
def get_brands(self, obj):
    brands = obj.category.all()
    serializer = BrandSerializerNested(brands, many=True)
    return serializer.data
```

But that does not make much sense: the [**`related_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) specifies the name of the relation in *reverse* so obtaining the `Brand`s for a given `Category`, you thus can rename these to:

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='brands'
    )
    #…
```

and work with a subserializer:

```
def get_brands(self, obj):
    brands = obj.brands.all()
    serializer = BrandSerializerNested(brands, many=True)
    return serializer.data
```

or just define `BrandSerializerNested` first and use:

```
class CategorySerializerNested(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    brands = serializers.BrandSerializerNested(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = '__all__'
```